# how to check if a file has an open licence in java ?

Tags: java, file-format

In the system of 5 Star Open Data, the first star is: " make your stuff available on the Web (whatever format) under an open license".

Using java, how can you check if an existing file on the web is under open license?

Comment: What do you know about the file?  Usually source files have the license at the start of each file. Usually JARs have the `LICENSE` as a file inside them.

Comment: If you mean for example checking for Apache License programmatically, it doesn't seem to be possible because it doesn't seem to be logical.

Comment: I want  to check when i download an image for example (or any format file which has or not an extension) to know if it is under open license. I can't find how to check that.